# Grails error Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null - on basic grails app

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Here is my simple domain class:

```
package projectmanagement

class Project {

    String Name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Save Method on Controller(generated using scaffolding):

```
def save() {
    def projectInstance = new Project(params)
    if (!projectInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            projectInstance.errors.allErrors.each {
                println it
            }
        render(view: "create", model: [projectInstance: projectInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'project.label', default: 'Project'), projectInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: projectInstance.id)
}
```

When I try to save the project I get the following error:

```
 Field error in object 'projectmanagement.Project' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes    [projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.error.projectmanagement.Project.name,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.error.name,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.error,project.name.nullable.error.projectmanagement.Project.name,project.name.nullable.error.name,project.name.nullable.error.java.lang.String,project.name.nullable.error,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.projectmanagement.Project.name,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.name,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable.java.lang.String,projectmanagement.Project.name.nullable,project.name.nullable.projectmanagement.Project.name,project.name.nullable.name,project.name.nullable.java.lang.String,project.name.nullable,nullable.projectmanagement.Project.name,nullable.name,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [name,class projectmanagement.Project]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
```

The sql log shows:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.version as version0_0_, this_.name as name0_0_ from project this_ limit ?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from project this_
```

params.dump() shows:

```
<org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap@6715e66f request=org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2a6e8f nestedDateMap=[:] wrappedMap=[name:kkjkj, create:Create, action:save, controller:project]>
```

I am using Grails 2.2 and Intellij Idea IDE. Though I've not used Grails for last 5-6 month but I can't recall having same problem before.

Comment: Make sure the `dynamic` data binding is appropriate. `params` has `name`?

Comment: added params.dump() on the question. It seems params has name.

Comment: Also most of the code is autogenerated. I've only created the domainclass.

Comment: @biztiger check your view. You have a field with the name name?

Comment: I edited `Name` to `name` but I guess has not been accepted yet by @biztiger. Looking at the error, it seems the domain class has the typo error while question was post but in actual it has `name`.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Really sorry to post a question, caused by typo mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this causes the problem but in your domain class `Name` starts with an upper case `N` while the parameter map contains `name` with lower case `n`.

Comment: Thanks much. I simply overlooked it.